# EF Core: How to add a column to all indexes for entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a SaaS application where I am defining entities that will implement an `ITenantAwareEntity` interface like so:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Entities that implement this interface will be restricted to writing to and reading from
/// their assigned tenant only.
/// </summary>
public interface ITenantAwareEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The tenant this entity belongs to.
    /// </summary>
    Guid TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

In my `OnModelCreating` method for the database context, I have code that will identify these entities and apply a global filter on the tenant id to ensure tenants are isolated.

I also want to examine all indexes for these tables to see if the TenantId is the first column in the index (or if there at all).

Personally, I'd prefer to just inject the `TenantId` column as the first column of the index, but the EF model has these as readonly properties, so... delete the old and replace with the original with an extra column, right? Not so easy to do.

I tried something like this:

```cs
//ensure that all indexes for the tenant-aware entity reference the tenant ID
var indexes = entityType.GetIndexes().ToList();
foreach (var index in indexes)
    if (index.Properties.All(i => i.Name != nameof(ITenantAwareEntity.TenantId)))
    {
        //make the tenant id the first column in the index.
        var props = new List<IMutableProperty>
            { entityTypeBuilder.Property(nameof(ITenantAwareEntity.TenantId)).Metadata };
        props.AddRange(index.Properties);
        entityType.AddIndex(props);
    }

foreach (var index in indexes)
{
    //with a new index created with the tenant id, remove the old index.
    entityType.RemoveIndex(index);
}
```

I split up creating the index and removing the index since I got yelled at for trying to change a collection while it was enumerated, but now I get a message like:

`The index {'TenantId'} cannot be removed from the entity type 'MyEntity' because it is defined on the entity type 'MyEntity'.`

...so I guess I'm still doing this wrong.

How do I remove/ replace an index while building the model, or failing that (preferably) just add a column to the front of the index?

Comment: By “index” you mean like an RDBMS `INDEX` on a table, right? Why not just do it in SQL directly? Are you using SSDT?

Comment: I don't want this to be manual... I want this to be automatic so that developers work on the entities but don't have to think about managing tenancy.

Comment: Right, but doing any kind of DDL in EF is an exercise in pain (EF is ultimately just an abstraction, after-all). Anyway, you **can** automate it by generating the `CREATE INDEX ON` statements from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views.

Comment: Well, that's pretty manual, the way I see it. I'd like a developer to create his or her entity, define the indexes for the business case, and then automatically (upon model building) supplement the indexes to include the tenant ID since all tenant-aware entities will have that filter. It seems the EF model builder has the necessary metadata to make this a (relatively) painless process... if I can get it to work.

Comment: I should probably note that the developers will not have direct access to the database, this is being done through ci/cd migrations.

Comment: _"this is being done through ci/cd migrations."_ - to be frank, _that strategy won't go well_. There's nothing wrong with having a production DB that devs can't access, but when you do that then you **need** someone acting as a DBA because EF migrations are a very, very blunt instrument. Personally I'd quit if I had to work in a place that imposed rules like that...

Comment: Looks like you are trying to remove index which you shouldn't (haven't replaced).  Have you tried moving `RemoveIndex` call right after `AddIndex` call and remove the second loop?  If still having issues/not getting what you want, please provide EF Core version and minimal repro to see what is going on. In general you should have more robust criterial which index to replace - for instance, if `TenantId` is not part of the PK, then FK covering indexes should not include it. etc.

Comment: Yes I tried that first, got yelled at for trying to modify a collection that had already been enumerated. Not clear on what you're saying in the second part of your comment.

Comment: `ToList()` call before `foreach` is preventing the "modify collection while enumerating" problem, so it's worth trying again what I suggested. What about the second part of my previous comment, I was trying to say that there are indexes which you shouldn't modify. In other words, the column should be added to *some* indexes, not *all*. The indexes created automatically by EF Core for FKs are good example of an index that shouldn't be modified (EF Core will restore them anyway).